# Sorting with an Array, Then saving the sorted array to a file in C#

Tags: c#

If there's an easy way than the way I've started, I'd love to see/hear it.
I posted earlier about doing a project, well I've gotten started on that project in C#.

I've been able to take source code from an webpage, save it to a file. Then pull that file back up and sort it in an array. The problem I'm having now is taking the newly organized Source Code in the array and saving it back to a file where it is still organized.

This is the snippet of code that needs work.

```
StreamWriter writer1 = new StreamWriter(fileName + ".txt");
writer1.Write(sourceCode);
writer1.Close();
reader.Close();
resp.Close();

string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(fileName+".txt");

foreach(string line in lines)
{
    Console.WriteLine(line);
}
```

I've tried a few things involving trying to assign lines to a variable, the whole string(idk why but i tried) and it didn't help.

Would it be easier to use an actual for loop in this instance?

Comment: "taking the newly organized Source Code in the array and saving it back to a file where it is still organized" - so, you mean:   'File.WriteAllLines(path, SortedList.ToArray())'?

Answer (score 0):

Inside your loop use a System.Text.StringBuilder

This has an append line function.

Then after your done looping, do File.WriteAllLines(path, builder.ToString())

Also, rather than using that stream writer, you can use File.WriteAllText(path, string)

Comment: So theory wise, how is this taking the array that's already been generated and saving it a new file. How is it different than say, adding a new stream writer? Does this way save on memory used and mitigate processing time?

Comment: Because your adding text to a string builder then saving that text to a file.

Comment: when i get to the File.WriteAllLines(path,builder.ToString()) builder doesnt populate, is a name I give the Stringbuilder?

Comment: Path and builder in this example would be variables showing the path to save and the builder you created and called appendline on.